# Ng-Tables grouping feature not working with server-side data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

Below is the `js` I'm using to group a list of results according to the `groupName` property in the returned array. Unfortunately the table isn't loading (it's completely blank), but I'm not getting an error in the console either. The documentation is incredibly sparse on the [plug-in's page](http://ng-table.com/#/grouping/demo-grouping-basic), so I'm wondering: how do I use the `getData` option and enable grouping w/the returned results.

```
    var getConnections = function(firmId){
        self.tableParams = $rootScope.gridParamsHash["groupsList"] || new NgTableParams({count: 25 }, {
            counts: [25, 50, 100],
            group: 'groupName',
            groupOptions: { isExpanded: true },
            getData: function(params){
                $scope.checkFilter();
                return connectionsService.getConnections(firmId, 
                                                         $scope.pagingParams, 
                                                         params.filter(), 
                                                         params.sorting())
                                         .then(connectionsData, connectionsError);
            } 
        });
    };

    var connectionsData = function(data){
        self.gridData = ata.connections;
        $scope.pagingParams.total = data.total;
        return self.gridData
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving the `group` property to the first object in the constructor solved the problem

```
        self.tableParams = $rootScope.gridParamsHash["groupsList"] || new NgTableParams({count: 25, group: 'groupName'}, {
            counts: [25, 50, 100],
            groupOptions: { isExpanded: false },
            getData: function(params){
                $scope.checkFilter();
                return connectionsService.getConnections(firmId, 
                                                         $scope.pagingParams, 
                                                         params.filter(), 
                                                         params.sorting())
                                         .then(connectionsData, connectionsError);
            } 
        }, 113600000);
```